# O que são as "query strings" em arquivos?

Tags: php

Estou aprendendo PHP e observando o link de um arquivo no cloud front vejo o seguinte:
"(...)cloudfront.net/v/2462380.mp4?Expires=1454618820(...)"

Quando tento acessar o arquivo sem essas "chaves" o servidor não retorna o arquivo.

Gostaria de saber como é feita essa "autenticação" e se isso é uma exclusividade do Cloud Front ou se é algo que posso implementar com PHP em um servidor comum?

Obg.

Answer (score 1):

Se você se refere a chave "Expires", provavelmente esse `1454618820` é somente um timestamp informando que horas o arquivo vai ser expirado, e você não consegue acessar sem essa chave porque o site faz uma verificação se essa chave existe.

O termo correto pra essas chaves são exatamente as query strings. Informações que você passa através da URL.

Facilmente vc pode implementar isso num servidor comum, por exemplo, pode fazer isso:

```
if(isset($_GET['Expires']) && $_GET['Expires'] >= time()){
     //permite o acesso
}else
    //não permite o acesso.
```